# How to enable sort on a field in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

In logstash I am parsing out the microseconds from my apache logs, how do I sort on this field in kibana?

Here is my filter for logs :

```
if [type] == "apachelogs" {
    grok {
      break_on_match => false
      match => { "message" => "\[%{HTTPDATE:apachetime}\]%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:verb}%{SPACE}/%{NOTSPACE:ApacheRequested}" }
match=> { "message" => "\*\*%{NUMBER:seconds}/%{NUMBER:microseconds}" }

       add_tag => "%{apachetime}"
       add_tag => "%{verb}"
       add_tag => "%{ApacheRequested}"
       add_tag => "%{seconds}"
       add_tag => "%{microseconds}"



    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "sorting"? Sorting performed where?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I want to visualise sorting in Kibana

Answer (score 2):

As long as Logstash is parsing the field you want to sort on, which it is, then it has no impact on your ability to sort in Kibana.

To sort in Kibana, in the discovery view, [add the field microseconds](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#adding-columns) (or any field you want to sort on). Then you can sort on that field, using the arrow near the field name.

Comment: That first part is not 100% accurate, but you are answering OP's question

Comment: @WillBarnwell if you can improve the accuracy of the first part, that would be great.

Comment: @WillBarnwell Thanks! I did not understood what was missing in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sort on the field? Thanks to your grok pattern your event now has a `microseconds` field with the value in it.

You can sort via simple `if` and `else if` checks. [*Logstash Docs on Conditionals*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals)

```
if [microseconds] <= 30000000 {
  # filter
} 
else if [microseconds] <= 60000000 {
  # filter
}
else {
  # filter
}
```

**EDIT:** This answer has no bearing on the Question, since OP was actually asking about sorting in Kibana, this is about sorting in Logstash

Comment: The microseconds was added as a tag, though, not a field?

Comment: The grok patern is making it a field and then the add tag is taking the value of the field and adding it as a tag

Comment: @WillBarnwell I want to visualise sorting in KIbana